Compute a Fourier integral with explicit form
I have a generating function $p(z) = \Big(\frac{1}{6}\cos(2z) - \frac{8}{3}\cos(z) + \frac{5}{2}\Big)^{\alpha/2}$, where $\alpha\in(0,2)$, then I want to find the explicit form of the following integral,
\begin{equation}
a_p = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}p(\xi)e^{-ip\xi}d\xi,
\end{equation}
with $p\in \mathbb{Z}$.
Can you provide some ideas for calculating this integral explicitly (rather than numerical integration)?

Maybe convert it into a contour integral, and use the $e^{i \theta}$ form instead of the cosines to make it easier to integrate? Another thing that might come in handy is the binomial expansion for rational powers, also called Newton's generalised binomial theorem: $$(x+y)^r = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{r}{k} x^{r-k} y^k $$

@Kraken, many thanks for your suggestions, I will have a try.
